# Why does the JButton becomes inactive after it has been clicked?

Tags: java, swing, sockets

After I have entered the username and password for the user, then click the button to send the stream to the server to determine if the user should be authenticated. The button stops working as though it has been disabled.

```
public class EmployeeSignIn extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JLabel lblUsername, lblPassword;
    private JTextField txtUsername;
    private JPasswordField jpfPassword;
    private JButton btnSubmit;
    private JPanel pnlButton, pnlLogo, pnlComponents1, pnlComponents2;
    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private ObjectInputStream ois;

    private void initializeStreamComponents() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 4200);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void initComponent() {
        initializeStreamComponents();

        lblUsername = new JLabel("Username");
        lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");

        txtUsername = new JTextField();

        jpfPassword = new JPasswordField();

        btnSubmit = new JButton("Sign In");

        pnlButton = new JPanel();
        pnlLogo = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        pnlComponents1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 3, 3));
        pnlComponents2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 3, 3));
    }

    private void addComponentsToPanel() {

        pnlLogo.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img/app.png")));

        pnlComponents1.add(lblUsername);
        pnlComponents1.add(txtUsername);

        pnlComponents2.add(lblPassword);
        pnlComponents2.add(jpfPassword);

        pnlButton.add(btnSubmit);
    }

    private void addPanelsToWindow() {
        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.add(pnlLogo);
        container.add(pnlComponents1);
        container.add(pnlComponents2);
        container.add(pnlButton);
    }

    private void registerListeners() {
        btnSubmit.addActionListener(this);
    }

    private void setWindowProperties() {
        this.setTitle("ARD-Employee");
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(450, 200);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public EmployeeSignIn() {
        this.initComponent();
        this.addComponentsToPanel();
        this.addPanelsToWindow();
        this.registerListeners();
        this.setWindowProperties();
    }

    private boolean validateFields() {
        if (!textFieldCheck(txtUsername)) {
            txtUsername.grabFocus();
            System.out.println(1);
            System.out.println("Please enter your username");
            System.out.println(2);
            return false;
        }

        if (!textFieldCharacterCheck(txtUsername)) {
            txtUsername.grabFocus();
            System.out.println("No Special Characters Allowed in Username!");
            return false;
        }

        if (!passwordFieldCheck(jpfPassword)) {
            jpfPassword.grabFocus();
            System.out.println("Please Enter your Password!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean textFieldCheck(JTextField field) {
        if (field.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            field.grabFocus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean passwordFieldCheck(JPasswordField field) {
        String password = new String(field.getPassword());
        if (password.trim().isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean textFieldCharacterCheck(JTextField field) {
        return field.getText().matches("^\\d+$");
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return txtUsername.getText();
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return new String(jpfPassword.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton src = (JButton) e.getSource();

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (src.equals(btnSubmit)) {
                    if (validateFields()) {
                        sendStreamsToServer();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void sendStreamsToServer() {
        try {

            String userType = "employee";
            oos.writeObject(userType);

            oos.writeObject(this.getUsername());
            System.out.println("USERNAME: " + this.getUsername());
            oos.writeObject(this.getPassword());
            System.out.println("PASSWORD: " + this.getPassword());

            String readObj = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("READ OBJECT: " + readObj);

            boolean validationCheck = (boolean) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Employee/VALIDATION CHECK: " + validationCheck);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.err.println(e1.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void closeConnection() {
        try {
            oos.close();
            ois.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new EmployeeSignIn();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ActionListener` is connecting to a `Socket`. A `Socket` blocks waiting for input. Since this code is executed on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`, the GUI freezes.

The solution is to connect to your `Socket` in a separate `Thread`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on the `EDT`. You may want to consider using the `SwingWorker` as your `Thread`. The `SwingWorker` API makes it easier to update the GUI when required.

Comment: I made a change to the actionPerformed method. Now the GUI does not freezes after it has been clicked. However, the server only responds once after the button has been clicked. On subsequent clicks nothing is sent from the server to the client. Can you suggest to me what could be causing this to happen?

Comment: @KMuir To use a Socket you need a "while loop" to keep waiting for data from the Socket. Take a look at the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html). There is section on `Sockets` to get you started.